# Error while compiling the script in installshield

Tags: installshield, installscript

When I wrote the codes below in the script, I received errors.

Errors:

```
Compiling...
Setup.Rul
•   C:\InstallShield 2023 Projects\My Project Name-1\Script Files\Setup.Rul(5) : error C8017: 'sResult' : expected typedef (struct) name
•   C:\InstallShield 2023 Projects\My Project Name-1\Script Files\Setup.Rul(5) : error C8008: '=' : identifier expected

•   C:\InstallShield 2023 Projects\My Project Name-1\Script Files\Setup.Rul(5) : error C8008: '' : identifier expected

•   C:\InstallShield 2023 Projects\My Project Name-1\Script Files\Setup.Rul(6) : error C8017: 'szTitle' : expected typedef (struct) name

•   C:\InstallShield 2023 Projects\My Project Name-1\Script Files\Setup.Rul(6) : error C8008: '=' : identifier expected

•   C:\InstallShield 2023 Projects\My Project Name-1\Script Files\Setup.Rul(6) : error C8008: 'Select Installation Folder' : identifier expected

•   C:\InstallShield 2023 Projects\My Project Name-1\Script Files\Setup.Rul(7) : error C8017: 'szPrompt' : expected typedef (struct) name

•   C:\InstallShield 2023 Projects\My Project Name-1\Script Files\Setup.Rul(7) : error C8008: '=' : identifier expected

•   C:\InstallShield 2023 Projects\My Project Name-1\Script Files\Setup.Rul(7) : error C8008: 'Please select the installation folder:' : identifier expected
•   C:\InstallShield 2023 Projects\My Project Name-1\Script Files\Setup.Rul(9) : error C8017: 'nResult' : expected typedef (struct) name

•   C:\InstallShield 2023 Projects\My Project Name-1\Script Files\Setup.Rul(9) : error C8008: '=' : identifier expected

•   C:\InstallShield 2023 Projects\My Project Name-1\Script Files\Setup.Rul(9) : error C8062: 'szTitle' : constant operand required

•   C:\InstallShield 2023 Projects\My Project Name-1\Script Files\Setup.Rul(9) : error C8014: 'szPrompt' : identifier already defined

•   C:\InstallShield 2023 Projects\My Project Name-1\Script Files\Setup.Rul(9) : error C8014: 'sResult' : identifier already defined

•   C:\InstallShield 2023 Projects\My Project Name-1\Script Files\Setup.Rul(9) : error C8022: ')' : comma or semicolon expected

•   C:\InstallShield 2023 Projects\My Project Name-1\Script Files\Setup.Rul(11) : error C8017: 'MessageBox' : expected typedef (struct) name

•   C:\InstallShield 2023 Projects\My Project Name-1\Script Files\Setup.Rul(11) : error C8008: '(' : identifier expected

•   C:\InstallShield 2023 Projects\My Project Name-1\Script Files\Setup.Rul(11) : error C8008: 'nResult = ' : identifier expected

•   C:\InstallShield 2023 Projects\My Project Name-1\Script Files\Setup.Rul(11) : error C8008: '+' : identifier expected

•   C:\InstallShield 2023 Projects\My Project Name-1\Script Files\Setup.Rul(11) : error C8062: 'nResult' : constant operand required

•   C:\InstallShield 2023 Projects\My Project Name-1\Script Files\Setup.Rul(11) : error C8022: ')' : comma or semicolon expected

•   C:\InstallShield 2023 Projects\My Project Name-1\Script Files\Setup.Rul(12) : error C8017: 'MessageBox' : expected typedef (struct) name

•   C:\InstallShield 2023 Projects\My Project Name-1\Script Files\Setup.Rul(12) : error C8008: '(' : identifier expected

•   C:\InstallShield 2023 Projects\My Project Name-1\Script Files\Setup.Rul(12) : error C8008: 'sResult = ' : identifier expected

•   C:\InstallShield 2023 Projects\My Project Name-1\Script Files\Setup.Rul(12) : error C8008: '+' : identifier expected

•   C:\InstallShield 2023 Projects\My Project Name-1\Script Files\Setup.Rul(12) : error C8014: 'sResult' : identifier already defined

•   C:\InstallShield 2023 Projects\My Project Name-1\Script Files\Setup.Rul(12) : error C8014: 'INFORMATION' : identifier already defined

•   C:\InstallShield 2023 Projects\My Project Name-1\Script Files\Setup.Rul(12) : error C8022: ')' : comma or semicolon expected

•   Setup.inx - 28 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

How can I get past the error?

```
STRING sResult;
NUMBER nResult;
STRING szTitle, szPrompt;

sResult = "";
szTitle = "Select Installation Folder";
szPrompt = "Please select the installation folder:";

nResult = SdAskDestPath(szTitle, szPrompt, sResult);

MessageBox("nResult = " + NumberToString(nResult), INFORMATION);
MessageBox("sResult = " + sResult, INFORMATION);
```

In addition to the log; Looks like he's nailed it.

```
****Logging started at 10/30/2023 01:02:23 ÖS ==================
Calculating size of cabinet files...
Copying uncompressed setup files...
ISDEV : error 136: Could not copy file 'C:\InstallShield 2023 Projects\My Project Name-1\Script Files\setup.inx' to 'C:\InstallShield 2023 Projects\My Project Name-1\Media\Release 1\Disk Images\Disk1\setup.inx' "The system cannot find the specified file"
Release 1 - 2 error(s), 0 warning(s)
Logging stopped at 10/30/2023 01:02:24 ÖS ==================
Log file has been created: <file:C:\InstallShield 2023 Projects\My Project Name-1\Media\Release 1\Log Files\10-30-2023 01-02-23 ÖS.txt>
**
**
```

I activated the Compiled compile before build checkbox, but I did not get any results.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoQOQ.png)